# SQL Server insert multiple rows efficiently

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have an old classic ASP application which needs to insert many thousand rows into a SQL Server 2008 table. Currently the application is sending an `INSERT` command for each row separately, which takes a long time and meanwhile locks the table.

Is there a better way to do this? For example maybe:

```
Insert all rows into a temp table
```

and then do

```
SELECT INTO from the temp table
```

?

Comment: where is the source of the rows to insert ?

Comment: Sql server can bulk insert directly from CSV  - this q&a mentions the technique though it's not spexidically asking how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917300/bulk-insert-from-csv-file-to-ms-sql-database

Comment: The source in in the application itself. It generates a list of dates and then needs to add them to the table.

Comment: This can not be done using a csv file due to server limitations.

Comment: Can you create a stored procedure that bulk adds rows based on parameters from the app?

Comment: Please post the app code doing the insert

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating the list of dates in the application itself, then you could probably generate them with the necessary additions to make this work.

In SQL Server 2008, you can insert multiple rows in a single command, which is a bit better than inserting row-by-row.

Here are a couple of examples of how you could do it, using a table variable for dummy data, and using `GETDATE()` to generate a few different dates (which you would obviously be generating in your application):

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE
(
      RowID         INT IDENTITY
     ,MyDate        DATETIME
)
;

INSERT INTO @TABLE (MyDate) 
VALUES 
     (GETDATE())
    ,(GETDATE()+1)
    ,(GETDATE()+2)
    ,(GETDATE()+3)
    ,(GETDATE()+4)
    ,(GETDATE()+5)
    ,(GETDATE()+6)

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
;
```

Returns:

```
RowID  | MyDate
1      | 26/11/2017 10:51:49
2      | 27/11/2017 10:51:49
3      | 28/11/2017 10:51:49
4      | 29/11/2017 10:51:49
5      | 30/11/2017 10:51:49
6      | 01/12/2017 10:51:49
7      | 02/12/2017 10:51:49
```

You can also use this format:

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE (MyDate)
SELECT GETDATE()
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 1
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 2
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 3
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 4
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 5
    UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE() + 6
;

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
;
```

Returns:

```
RowID  | MyDate
1      | 26/11/2017 10:51:49
2      | 27/11/2017 10:51:49
3      | 28/11/2017 10:51:49
4      | 29/11/2017 10:51:49
5      | 30/11/2017 10:51:49
6      | 01/12/2017 10:51:49
7      | 02/12/2017 10:51:49
```

Not an ASP expert, but if you're concatenating the string in your application, you should be able to concatenate the string continuously rather than recreating it as a whole new `INSERT` statement for each date.